# How to contribute information (we need a FAQ or wiki)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

By accident I found this excelent post by Edgar Bonet, [How can I handle the millis() rollover?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-can-i-handle-the-millis-rollover/12588#12588). That *is not exactly a question, rather a tutorial in a question/answer format* (his words).

This valuable information is lost among thousand of other questions. I think we need a FAQ or wiki to put this information, to better server our charter.

Second, Is it an acceptable format for posting original/curated material?

Answer (score 2):

I have done similar questions, such as [How do you use SPI on an Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16348/how-do-you-use-spi-on-an-arduino/). It is certainly [OK to post a question and answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

The intent of Stack Exchange in general is to become a repository of useful questions and answers. Sometimes a single person will do both the question and answer, and at other times one person will ask a very interesting question, and another person will do an excellent answer.

This site is therefore working as intended. Unfortunately sometimes good questions are swamped by poor ones, but the really poor questions should be closed (by community voting), leaving behind the good ones.